# If a matrix of the form I + B is singular, then ||B|| ≥ 1 for every subordinate norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I need some guidance showing that:

If a matrix of the form I+B is singular, where I is the identity matrix, then for any subordinate norm $\|\cdot\|$, $\|B\|\geq1$.

Comment: What happens if $\| B \|<1$? You may want to consider the Neumann series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the matrix is singular, then for some $v$ with $\|v\| = 1$, we have $(I+B)v = 0$, that is, $Bv = -v$. Hence $\|B\| = \sup_{\|y\|\le 1} \|By\|  \ge \|Bv\| = \|-v\|=1$.